# iOS Adding colors to star rating image depending on score

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have image [ratingImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZWFb.png) (attached).I need to color only the stars depending upon the rating. for e.g 2.5, need to color only 2 and a half stars. any pointers to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of ways you could achieve this with the image you have.

1. Make your stars and half-stars separate UIImageView objects and children of the imageview you have. Turn the right ones on and off depending on the rating score. Or instead of turning them on and off set their images to full, half, or no star images.
2. You only have 10 different possible states. You could make separate images for each rating score and use the appropriate one depending on the rating.
3. Put a view behind your image and change its width depending on the rating. Your rating image has transparency for the stars, so the bar behind it will fill in the transparent start parts.

Comment: I have been trying the point 3 but it not working . any code snippet which would help me ?